# making runtime variable names global in perl

Tags: perl, variables, dynamic, global-variables

OK, I've looked hard and have tried a myriad of variations to get this to work.  I need some help from the perl experts.

First of all, I know, I know, don't use dynamic variable names!  Well, I think I need to do so in this case.  I'm fixing an *inherited* script.  It has a set of variables that are formed with `prefix` + `"_"` + `suffix`.  This started small, but prefix is now a list of about 20 and suffix of about 50 -- a thousand different variables.

The script in some cases loops over these variables, using `eval` to retrieve an individual value, etc..  This all works.  The problem is, all uses of the different variables throughout the script, whether inside a loop on the prefix and/or suffix or just a hardcoded use, assume that these variables are *globalized* by using `use var qw($varname)`.  The number of `use vars` hardcoded statements has grown out of control.  Moreover, there are thousands of past input profile files that initialize these variables using global syntax, all of which need to continue to work.

I was hoping I could improve maintainability by doing the *globalization* step in a loop, dynamically creating the variable names one at a time, then globalizing them with `use vars` or `our`.  Here is some code to show what I'm after.  I've shown several options here, but each is actually a separate trial.  I have tried other variations and cannot keep them straight anymore.

```
my @prefixes   = ("one", "two", ..., "twenty");
my @suffixes   = ("1", "2", ..., "50");
my $globalvars = "";
for my $suffix (@suffixes) {
    for my $prefix (@prefixes) {
        # option 1 -- remainder of #1 outside of loop
        # NOTE: 1.a (no comma); 1.b (include comma between vars)
        $globalvars .= "\$$prefix\_$suffix, ";

        # option 2
        eval "use vars qw(\$$prefix\_$suffix)";

        # option 3
        my $g = "$prefix\_$suffix";
        eval ("use vars qw(\$$g)");

        # option 4
        eval ("our \$$g");
    }
}

# option 1.a
use vars qw($globalvars);
# or option 1.b
my (eval "$globalvars");
:
:
:
# now use them as global variables
if ($one_1 eq ...) {
    if ($one_10) {
```

It seems that the problem with "use vars" (besides the fact that it is discouraged) is that the string inside qw has to be the actual variable name, not a dynamic variable name.  The 'eval' options don't work, I think, because the scope only exists within the eval itself.

Is there a way to do this in perl?

Comment: I know it isn't your fault, but this is a case study in why using a variable as a variable name is a horror. I would suggest considering shoehorning some hashes in, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for `eval EXPR` since there's no need to use `qw`. `qw` is just one way to create a list of strings, and one that's not particularly useful to your needs.

```
my @prefixes;  BEGIN { @prefixes = qw( one two ... twenty ); }
my @suffixes;  BEGIN { @suffixes = 1..50; }

use vars map { my $p = $_; map { '$'.$p.'_'.$_ } @suffixes } @prefixes;
```

Comment: This works when both lists are defined in the same file.  In my case, the `@suffixes` list is actually defined in another file, which is brought in with a `require` statement.  I tried putting `BEGIN` around the definition of `@suffixes` in the other file, but `perl -c myprog.pl` reveals that all the global uses are illegal.  Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you load the other file, and does it have a `package` statement?

Comment: `require otherDefs.pl;`  and no, it does not have a `package` statement.  Actually, I lied.  `otherDefs.pl` includes `yetAnotherFile.pl` and that one has the definition of `@suffixes`.  Neither of them has a `package` statement.

Comment: Just add `BEGIN { require 'otherDefs.pl' }` before the code I posted.

Comment: After a bit of rearranging, it all works now.  (The `otherDefs.pl` could not be run at `BEGIN` time, due to other content, so I separated out the stuff that was hardcoded and could be `required` inside a `BEGIN`.)  I chose this answer over the one by @choroba because @ikegami showed how to combine the two lists, which was part of my problem.

Answer (score 6):

> string inside qw has to be the actual variable name, not a dynamic variable name

That's how `qw` works, it quotes words, it does no interpolation. You don't have to use `qw` with `use vars`, though.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @global_vars;
BEGIN { @global_vars = qw($x $y) }
use vars @global_vars;

# strict won't complain:
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
```

BEGIN is needed here, because `use vars` runs in compile time, and we need @global_vars to be already populated.